# Not able to display JPEG image in ImageView

Tags: java, android

I want to display the below JPEG image in an ImageView.
[image: target image]

Android Device is not able to decode the Image. Log Cat is showing this message: decoder->decode returned false. The image is loading correctly on PC and in chrome(Mobile). I've tried various solutions already on the StackOverflow, None of them worked. Currently, I'm displaying the image in a WebView and It's working fine.

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator+"0101YC17000000000003.jpeg")
```

It's not an optimal solution, so I want to display the image in ImageView from the external storage. 
Original Image: [0101YC17000000000003.jpeg](http://xdeveloper.esy.es/0101YC17000000000003.jpeg)

Comment: more information is needed, like do you want to store this image in your app then display it or do you want android to get the image from specific location then display it.

Comment: if you just want to display the image in imageView just copy and paste the image in drawable folder and then in xml set the source of the imageview

Comment: @AnkushRawat Yes, I can set the source in xml file. The problem is Android device is not able to decode the attached Image. it's giving decoder->decode returned false.

Comment: Yeah, I've had this same issue in the past. There seems to be a little beef between the android system and jpeg.